# How to convert nested loop construct into flow chart in C?

Tags: c, nested-loops, flowchart

I'm drawing this code

```
if (V > 24)
{
    do
    {
        PWM();

        while (I = 0)
        {
            RA5 = 0;
            LED();
            I2C();
            Delay_ms(1000);
            RA5 = 1;
            Delay_ms(1000);

            if (I != 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        LED();
        I2C();
    } while (v < 28.7)
}
```

to this

[image: flow_chart]

I really don't know how to deal with this nested loop, is there any better idea for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unrelated, but

```
    if(I != 0){
        break;
    }
```

Is implied by the for loop, you don't need it.  Also be careful:

```
while(I=0)
```

will set I to 0 and your loop will never exit!  You may have found this and decided to add the break later to compensate.  What you want is:

```
while(I==0)
```

Note that what you did with the do while is correct, and a while loop is the same except the check happens before entering the loop rather then when exiting the loop.  Remove the break and have your arrow simply go back to before the check for I == 0.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not well and this is my first time visiting here. I would assure myself knowing what you mean.

Comment: "Unrelated" 
What do you mean unrelated? is the material unrelated to the website? or I posted it wrong 
You meant "if statement is implied by for loop" Does that become
for(i=0; i !=0;  ){
    statement;
}

Comment: Can I use "Answer Your Question" button to response your comment?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by 'unrelated' is that the first part of my answer isn't necessary to answer your question but might be something you want to know anyway.